# Keyboard shortcut to hide results panel in MySQL Workbench

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mysql-workbench

In MS Query Analyzer you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to hide the results section, making your query window bigger and saving on scrolling up and down

Is there a keyboard shortcut in MySQL Workbench v6.2 to do this? I can't find it

Comment: Since the answer has been given (no, there isn't), are you looking to give the bounty to a workaround? If so, what OS are you on? Creating a workaround should be trivial

Comment: @Tyrsius, yes, to a good one of course that I will give the bounty.  Please notice my own answer as "minimum threshold" and give something with less keystokes, not missing focus over input panel, not missing result grid, etc... (obvious, no mouse!)

Comment: in my case is: workbench 6.2.5.0 build 379 (32 bits) Comunity over Windows 7

Answer (score 17):

I will share my own trick (not so nice): I mark one new line (or some spaces), after that, I "execute" that empty query with `shift-ctrl-enter` so the empty query generates an empty resultset and the grid is then hidden.

Comment: Since the answer has been given (no, there isn't), are you looking to give the bounty to a workaround? If so, what OS are you on? Creating a workaround should be trivial

Comment: superb trick, this should be marked as answer

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no shortcut to hide the result set for an sql editor. You only can use the close button in the tab title or run a query that doesn't return a result set.

Comment: That button shows/hides the output area for me, not the results grid. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

There is a close button Beneath the result grid, simply click to close. I am using workbench version 8.0. the following image shows it:- 
[image]